# how can I accelerate mutt sending speed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, while-loop, mutt

I am sending promotion emails using mutt in a bash script, but I can not send more than 400-500 mails per minute.

I would like to know if I can send emails faster by

1- Optimizing my shell (especially while loop)
2- Putting the file containing mails directly as input for mutt (that way I will not use any loop)
3- Other solution maybe .. ?

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line
do
echo "body" | mutt -e "my_hdr From: $from <me@gmail.com>" -s "subject"  $line
done < "$input"
```

Comment: Search 'bulk emailing' on the web

Comment: thank you Gilles, I am already using some smtp clients on Windows allowing me to bulk email .. but I am trying to make my script work faster with mutt

Answer (score 2):

A standard MUA such as mutt is not a good option for high-speed mail sending.  You'd be better off connecting directly to a mail server using your preferred SMTP library and sending directly that way.  There are libraries that do this for almost any language.  If you use a threaded language like Rust, you can get very high performance assuming the destination server is capable of handling it.  Anything you do in shell or with an MUA will be much slower even than a dynamic language like Ruby.

There isn't going to be a way that you can make your script much faster.  The shell invocation is not the performance problem here; it's the fact that mutt is optimized for human beings instead of high throughput.  It's just not the right tool for the job.

Also, since it sounds like you're unfamiliar with some of the intricacies of sending bulk email, I should point out that sending email which is unsolicited (that is, the user has not explicitly and affirmatively opted in to receiving it) and bulk (that is, you're sending substantially similar messages to multiple people) is spam, which is unethical and possibly illegal.  You very definitely should not do that and should be careful to honor any policies that your mail provider has on sending bulk or high-speed emails.